# Repository pattern and IQueryable<> generating bad SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4, repository-pattern, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5

I'm using the Repository Pattern on a small .NET 4.5, MVC4, EF5 project.

I've noticed that if I alter the results of an IQueryable object passed from the repository, the generated SQL is less than desirable.

For example, in my repository:

```
    public IQueryable<Entry> GetEntries()
    {
        // (db is an instance of the data context)
        return db.Entries.Where(e => e.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
    }
```

In my controller, I limit the amount of rows returned and sort it:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // (repo is an instance of the repository object)
        var entries = repo.GetEntries().Take(10).OrderByDescending(o => o.Created)
        return View(entries);
    }
```

This generates the following SQL:

```
DECLARE @p__linq__0 int = 1

SELECT 
[Project1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project1].[Created] AS [Created], 
[Project1].[LastModified] AS [LastModified], 
[Project1].[BodyOriginal] AS [BodyOriginal], 
[Project1].[BodyFormatted] AS [BodyFormatted], 
[Project1].[FormatterVersion] AS [FormatterVersion], 
[Project1].[BodyDigest] AS [BodyDigest], 
[Project1].[FollowupId] AS [FollowupId], 
[Project1].[AddMethod] AS [AddMethod], 
[Project1].[Entry_Id] AS [Entry_Id]
FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
        [Extent1].[Created] AS [Created], 
        [Extent1].[LastModified] AS [LastModified], 
        [Extent1].[BodyOriginal] AS [BodyOriginal], 
        [Extent1].[BodyFormatted] AS [BodyFormatted], 
        [Extent1].[FormatterVersion] AS [FormatterVersion], 
        [Extent1].[BodyDigest] AS [BodyDigest], 
        [Extent1].[FollowupId] AS [FollowupId], 
        [Extent1].[AddMethod] AS [AddMethod], 
        [Extent1].[Entry_Id] AS [Entry_Id]
        FROM [dbo].[Entries] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[Created] DESC
```

As you can see, the generated SQL is highly redundant.

If I change the repository method to include truncated and sorted results:

```
    public IQueryable<Entry> GetEntries()
    {
        // (db is an instance of the data context)
        return db.Entries.Where(e => e.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId).Take(10).OrderByDescending(o => o.Created);
    }
```

The generated SQL is better:

```
DECLARE @p__linq__0 int = 1

SELECT 
            [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
            [Extent1].[Created] AS [Created], 
            [Extent1].[LastModified] AS [LastModified], 
            [Extent1].[BodyOriginal] AS [BodyOriginal], 
            [Extent1].[BodyFormatted] AS [BodyFormatted], 
            [Extent1].[FormatterVersion] AS [FormatterVersion], 
            [Extent1].[BodyDigest] AS [BodyDigest], 
            [Extent1].[FollowupId] AS [FollowupId], 
            [Extent1].[AddMethod] AS [AddMethod], 
            [Extent1].[Entry_Id] AS [Entry_Id]
            FROM [dbo].[Entries] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0
  ORDER BY [Extent1].[Created] DESC
```

---

**How do I overcome this issue, that is make use of the repository pattern while still having the flexibility of modifying the results of the repository without created poorly-constructed SQL?**

Comment: The redundancy does not affect performance in this case.

Comment: I don't think you're showing the same queries.  Notice that the second query has no Order by clause.  That would seem to indicate it's not actually doing the same thing.

Comment: If they are the same, then that means Linq is probably optimizing the second query by doing the Take and OrderBy in memory rather than in SQL, which could be because it can "see" more of it.. though I can't be certain.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it was a simple cut-and-paste issue.

Comment: This is the repository anti pattern, it's better to remove that 'repository'. If you really want to use the Repository, define an interface which has nothing to do with EF and no method returns IQueryable. Also, the use of a repository or not is unrelated to how EF generates sql.

Comment: @MikeSW Great insight. If you want to change your comment into an answer I'll happily mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the repository anti pattern, it's better to remove that 'repository'. If you really want to use the Repository, define an interface which has nothing to do with EF and no method returns IQueryable. Also, the use of a repository or not is unrelated to how EF generates sql.